# Is it possible to delete an addin from memory when using MAF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, maf

I'm working on a project where administrators need to be able to add/delete/edit addins. The addins consist of 3 different dll's and 2 configuration files. when the addin hasn't been loaded ever i can delete it. however, when a user is currently using or has used the addin, I am no longer able to remove it without getting an Unauthorized access exception.

I'm able to delete the configuration files but not the dll's.

Is it possible to delete addins completely without restarting IIS or the site?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this classic asp or asp.net mvc?

Comment: asp mvc. running on framework 4.5 and IIS 7.5

Comment: @DanielMcGrath Do you actually use MAF (System.AddIn) or did you really mean MEF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unauthorized access exception is likely being thrown because the dll is in use. Even it if wasn't, deleting it would restart your application since ASP.NET monitors assembly and config file changes and automatically restarts the application.

Comment: So once an addin has been loaded, there is no way to remove it without restarting the application?

Comment: No, not if it's in use. [ScrewTurn wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) had a similar add-in model, but I they had code to restart the application when you add/remove add-ins.

Comment: ok, thank you very much! :) I've been struggling trying to get this to work. I'll just implement a passive solution and attempt to remove them when the site starts up.